# How to filter after split() in rdd spark scala?

Tags: apache-spark, filter, split

```
1,John,NY
2,Bill,FL
3,Harry,TX
```

I have a textfile with above data.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path").map(x=>(x.split(",")(0).toInt,x.split(",")(1),x.split(",")(2)))
```

After this how can i filter data where name is Bill or number is > 2 ? Or is there another way to do it without split function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` function.

```
df
.map(x=>(x.split(",")(0).toInt,x.split(",")(1),x.split(",")(2)))
.filter(row => row._2 == "Bill" || row._1 > 2)
```